# Grab text from cell to use as reference in script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to move the contents of, ...
cell J12 in sheet named **chart**
to,
cell **XXXX** in sheet named ***plants***.

(**XXXX** is a cell reference as text [an example is: HO96], located in K13 in the sheet named **chart**. This cell text can change, so I can not enter HO96 manually instead of XXXX in script below).

I tried recording a macro as below, but XXXX below needs to be the contents of cell K13.

```
function nxfCopyPaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J12').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('plants'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('XXXX').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('chart!J12').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('chart'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D19:E23').activate();
}
```

I am stuck on how to add this dynamic text as a cell reference. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is read the contents of a cell, you can do so as follows:

```
function nxfCopyPaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('chart');
  var rangeText = sheet.getRange('K13').getDisplayValue(); // I usually use getDisplayValue(), but you can also use getValue()

  spreadsheet.getRange('J12').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('plants'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange(rangeText).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('chart!J12').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('chart'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D19:E23').activate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, I am glad you edited my script because I can follow what you did easily. I will now add rangeText to my increasing 'range' of script variables